# Generate and download a file .doxc in flutter web with docx_template: ^0.3.3

Tags: flutter, templates, web, docx

i´m trying generate and download a file .docx generated with docx_template: ^0.3.3, actually i have this (generate):

```
final d = await docx.generate(c);

//Get external storage directory
//final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
//Get directory path
//String path = directory.path;

final of = File('Engranes Rectos Sistema Ingles.docx');
if (d != null) await of.writeAsBytes(d);
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: @nvoigt i can't download the file

Comment: What do you mean "download the file"? Do you expect a download in your browser? Where do you execute this code, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead?